How to upload image on confluence using python?
I am using the below code to upload an image on confluence. It works fine but if the page is heavy script is not able to upload image on confluence and throws the error 413. Can anyon please help me to modify my code?
import requests, base64
from datetime import date
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

auth_key = base64.b64encode(b"email:api").decode("ascii")

headers = { "Authorization": "Basic " + str(auth_key)} session = requests.session()


def optimize_image(image_path, max_width=500, max_height=800): 
    with Image.open(image_path) as img: 
        img = img.convert("RGB")
        img.thumbnail((max_width, max_height))
        buffer = BytesIO()
        img.save(buffer, format='JPEG')
        buffer.seek(0)
        return buffer

def optimize_image_2(image_path, max_width=200, max_height=300):
    with Image.open(image_path) as img: 
        img = img.convert("RGB") 
        img.thumbnail((max_width, max_height))
        buffer = BytesIO() img.save(buffer, format='JPEG')
        buffer.seek(0)
        return buffer








def dataget(page_id, title, encoded_image): 
    page response = session.get(f"https://domain.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/{page_id}", headers=headers) current_version = response.json()["version"]["number"]
    
    # Get the content of the page
                content_response=session.get(f"https://domain.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/{page_id}/?expand=body.storage",headers=headers)
    current_content = content_response.json()["body"]["storage"]["value"]
    
    # Append the new image to the existing content
    current_dateTime = date.today()
    new_image = f'<table><tr><td>{str(current_dateTime)}</td><td><div><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{encoded_image}" /></div></td></tr></table>'
    new_content = current_content + new_image
    
    # Increment the version number by 1
    new_version = current_version + 1
    
    # Set up the new content for the page
    new_content_data = {
        "id": page_id,
        "type": "page",
        "title": title,
        "space": {
            "key": "SpaceKey"
        },
        "body": {
            "storage": {
                "value": new_content,
                "representation": "storage"
            }
        },
        "version": {
            "number": new_version
        }
    }
    return new_content_data

def update(title, page_id, image):  
    encoded_image = base64.b64encode(optimize_image(image_file).read()).decode('utf-8') new_content = dataget(page_id, title, encoded_image)
    
    # Retrieve the current version number of the page
    response = session.get(f"https://domain.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/{page_id}", headers=headers)
    current_version = response.json()["version"]["number"]
    
    # Update the new content with the correct version number
    new_content["version"]["number"] = current_version + 1
    
    # Send the request to update the page
    response = session.put(f"https://domain.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/{page_id}?version={current_version+1}",
                           headers=headers, json=new_content)
    
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.content)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print('Request is successful.')
        return True
    else:
        print('Request returned an error compressing the image')
        encoded_image = base64.b64encode(optimize_image_2(image).read()).decode('utf-8')
        new_content = dataget(page_id, title, encoded_image)
        # Send the request to update the page
        response = session.put(f"https://domain.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/{page_id}",headers=headers,
                               json=new_content)
    
        print(response.status_code)
        print(response.content)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print('Request is successful.')
            return True
        else:
            print('Request returned an error')

update('pagename', 'pageid', 'image')

I tried to compree image as minimul but didn't work. I tried this library but had an issue to accessing from atlassian import Confluence
I want to attched the image rather than upload. I also don't want to loose the data present on page. BUt because of below line the request become heavy and throws the erro 413
"new_content = current_content + new_image"
